# How do I find all files of a specific type that are outside of a folder?

Tags: macos, applications, mojave, search

I want to find all .app files on my Mac that aren't in the  Applications folder. How do I do this?

---

## Please unmark as duplicate

1st point: The suggested dupe's answer explains how to get a list of all applications installed, but does not explain how to exclude the Applications folder.

> 1. How do I find all files of a specific type that are outside of a folder?
> 2. I want to find all .app files on my Mac that aren't in the  Applications folder. How do I do this?

2nd point: This is a 2-part question. The 1st part is a generic question that asks how to find ANY files of a certain kind not in a folder. The 2nd part is the situation specific to myself. The suggested dupe partially solves my own problem but doens't address the generic question.

https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/217115

3rd point: Furthermore, a key word in this question is "find." The suggested dupe's answer works to get a list of all installations, but it's not possible to get to where they're stored on the disk.

Comment: Heavily edited to focus on the specific problem you've described in your edit. If the answers you get don't help you to solve the more general aspect please ask a new question for this.

Answer (score 5):

Basically you take the list of applications found and filter out those who are in `/Applications`:

```
find / -type d -iname *.app | grep -v '^/Applications' > ~/applications.txt
```

The more elaborated way skips `/Applications` from the start and just lists `.app`s found in other directories:

```
find / -type d \( \( -depth 1 -name Applications -prune \) -o -name '*.app' -print \)
```

In both cases you might get warning messages if `find` tries to descend into a directory not accessible to the current user. You can prevent this by running the command with `sudo`.

Comment: I highly prefer the second one (you don't scan a directory for nothing).

Answer (score 2):

Here's another solution using `find`. We negate the predicate `-path` with an `!`- exclamation point. Use the `-x` option to prevent descending into other devices (filesystems) and send any error messages to the bit bucket- `2>/dev/null`.

```
find -x / ! -path '/Applications/*' -type d -name '*.app' 2>/dev/null
```